# Run multiple versions of firefox at same time

Tags: firefox

Is there a **easy way** to run multiple versions of firefox (3.5 and 3.6) at same time?

(I installed 3.6 in normal way and for 3.5 I'm using portableapp.com version.)

Comment: You should tell us what OS you are using.  The answer will depend on that.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that with gbjbaanb's method, you cannot run them side by side, it just allows you to open up one type of firefox, close it then open another else you would get a message saying:

`"Firefox is already running"`

What you can do is make two different profiles.

(I'm assuming Windows)

go to the firefox shortcut right click and select `properties` and add -p  to the target
to get: `C:\whereveryouinstalledit\FirefoxPortable.exe -p`

This will open up the profile manager. Create a new one, then exit. Go to where the profiles are stored which is different for OSes copy paste your default data into your new profile. (XP is in application data/mozilla/firefox/profiles)

then create two shortcuts and add the profile name after the -p

`C:\whereveryouinstalledit\FirefoxPortable.exe -p default`
`C:\whereveryouinstalledit\FirefoxPortable.exe -p name 2`

I think this'll work if you create a new profile for either the Portable or 3.6

I believe that you also need to add `-no-remote` to the non default firefox( if one is the default)

I've only done this with 3.5 and 3.6 installed the normal way though, never tried with portable.

anyway, I hope it helps.

Comment: I couldn't start it with C:\whereveryouinstalledit\FirefoxPortable.exe -p It still says "Firefox is already running" //Yes, Im running WindowsXP